# PCManFM actions not tracked in zeitgeist

Tags: lubuntu, zeitgeist, pcmanfm

`zeitgeist` and `gnome-activity-journal` seem like a good answer to many of my family-tech-support issues.  (I can't find the document I just edited!) Installed them on family Lubuntu machines and, in the main, they seem to work well.

However, a leading cause of family-tech-support issues is operations performed in Lubuntu's file manager PCManFM. These actions don't seem to be tracked by `zeitgeist` and upon looking in `zeitgeist-explorer`, PCManFM is not listed in the Applications panel.

Is there a way to add PCManFM to the `zeitgeist` logging?  `zeitgeist-explorer` has a remove button, but not an add one, for applications.  Perhaps there is a plugin, but I haven't found it.

Alternatively, since these applications don't seem to be under active development, is there a better option, one that includes PCManFM?